# How Do You Change the Pitch of a Sample In Alchemy Without Affecting Speed?

Tags: logic-pro, samples

If you take a vocal sample and drop it into Logic Pro X's Alchemy in sampler mode, can you play the samples at higher than normal pitches without the speed of the sample getting faster? I know there's a less than elegant work around for the EXS24, but is there a way to do this in Alchemy?

Comment: You can use the Granular mode. Is there a specific reason you want to stick with the Sampler mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the pitch of a Source's sample using the Coarse & Fine Tune controls as well as the using flex controls within logic itself >
Inspector > Region > Transpose

Logic can also render an audio sample into the step editor giving you Melodyne-ish control of pitch, timing, vibrato etc.